# Join with the highest value in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have two tables, students and school_year.

```
students
---------
ID  Name
---------
1   ABC
2   XYZ

school_year
-----------
ID  student_id  grade year
--------------------------
1   1           5     2011
2   1           6     2012
3   2           1     2010
4   2           2     2011
5   2           3     2012
```

I join them and get this result

```
select s.*, sy.grade, sy.year
from students s
left join school_year sy
on s.id=sy.student_id
order by s.name
```

and I get this result

```
id name        grade year
---------------------------
1   ABC        5     2011
1   ABC        6     2012
2   XYZ        1     2010
2   XYZ        2     2011
2   XYZ        3     2012
```

I would like to join school year table where grade is maximum/highest for the student so the table would look like this.

```
id name       grade  year
-------------------------
1  ABC        6      2012
2  XYZ        3      2012
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, sy1.grade, sy1.year FROM school_year sy1
LEFT JOIN school_year sy2
  ON sy1.student_id = sy2.student_id AND sy1.grade < sy2.grade
JOIN students s ON sy1.student_id = s.id
WHERE sy2.grade IS NULL
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3313e/1).